# Only check checkbox if popup = yes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a `checkbox` in a `datagridview` that I need a yes/no popup to confirm the transaction on the SQL side.  This part works fine but if I select NO, the checkbox still checks.

How would I go about making sure that the checkbox has the correct value on the UI?

The code I use is in `cellcontentclick` and the code for the correct checkbox is below:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex.ToString() == "3")
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)caseSelectorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];

    DataGridViewRow row = caseSelectorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRow;

    System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
    newCityCollectionDataSet.CaseSelectorRow SelectedRow;

    SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)caseSelectorBindingSource.Current;
    SelectedRow = (newCityCollectionDataSet.CaseSelectorRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes && Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value) == false) 
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value) == false && caseSelectorDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var matchedCaseNumber = (from c in dc.GetTable<CaseSelector>()
                                     where c.CaseNumberKey == SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey
                                     select c).SingleOrDefault();

            var matchedCaseNumberProp = (from d in dc.GetTable<PropertyInformation>()
                                         where d.CaseNumberKey == SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey
                                         select d).SingleOrDefault();

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
            reportsSent newReport = new reportsSent();
            newReport.CaseNumberKey = SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey;
            dc.reportsSents.InsertOnSubmit(newReport);
            matchedCaseNumberProp.DateFinished = DateTime.Now;
            matchedCaseNumberProp.Finished = -1;

            dc.SubmitChanges();

            SelectedRow.FinishedDate = DateTime.Now;
            SelectedRow.FinishedID = Globals.GlobalInt;
            SelectedRow.Finished = -1;

            caseSelectorTableAdapter.Update(newCityCollectionDataSet);

            var qry = dc.PropertyInformations.Where(c => c.DateFinished >= firstDay && c.DateFinished <= today && c.ClientKey == 2).Count();
            var qry1 = dc.PropertyInformations.Where(c => c.DateFinished >= firstDay && c.DateFinished <= today && c.ClientKey == 3).Count();

            txtFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(qry);
            txtGRBFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(qry1);
            txtFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(qry);

            PerformRefresh();
        }
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you're setting a checked status for true or false... You have calls to functions that you haven't shown us which may hold the error. Also you should remove irrelevant code and comment your code if you want helpful answers.

Comment: Setting the checked status is done by default when clicked in c# winform datagridview checkboxes.  I have no idea where to access that so I can make sure it only occurs when I want it to and hence the question.  All I do is pass the value -1 to the database.

Comment: You can see you're accessing it from `checkCell.Value` in that code above.

Comment: Sure but if I remove that code it still checks the box.

Comment: I didn't mean that code is setting it, I was saying you can see where to access it from that. Seems you've solved your problem anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming I've read the question right, try:

```
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    checkCell.Value = checkCell.FalseValue;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not get the job done.  It still leaves the box checked.  Thanks for that though I was not aware of .FalseValue!

Comment: PerformRefresh is just a method I wrote that refreshes the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No) return;
```